# How to manipulate and collate data in an associate array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following array of data

```
2889    1   1062
2889    8   John Smith
2889    6   0.29
2891    1   1117
2891    8   Jamie Dean
2891    6   2
2892    1   1062
2892    8   John Smith
2892    6   4
```

The First column is a list of entry IDs relating to form entries from a website, the second column is a list of meta_keys relating to fields in the form, and the final column is the data from those fields.

What I need to be able to do is collate the data in the array so that for each person I have:

```
ID Number(Meta_key 1)
Name(Meta_key 8)
Sum(Hours Owed(Meta_key 6))
```

I am lost on how to even start this task, any help would be very much appreciated.

This data has all been pulled from a database with the following query:

```
select 
    entry_id,
    meta_key,
    meta_value
from 
    staff_gf_entry_meta 
where 
    form_id = 48 
and 
    entry_id in (
        select 
            entry_id 
        from 
            staff_gf_entry_meta 
        where 
            meta_key = 7 
        and 
            form_id = 48 
        and 
            meta_value <= '2018-12-18' 
        and 
            meta_value >= '2018-12-12'
    )
and (
    meta_key = 1
    or
    meta_key = 8
    or
    meta_key = 6)
```

If needed the query can be altered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want a `GROUP BY` statement with the `SUM` aggregate function. To get all the key/value pairs in a row, you need to `JOIN` multiple queries.

```
SELECT 
    `mk1`.`meta_value`        `Number`, 
    `mk8`.`meta_value`        `Name`,
    SUM(`mk6`.`meta_value`)   `Hours Owed`
  FROM
    `staff_gf_entry_meta`  `mk1`

  INNER JOIN  
    `staff_gf_entry_meta`  `mk6`
  USING
    (`entry_id`, `form_id`)

  INNER JOIN  
    `staff_gf_entry_meta`  `mk7`
  USING
    (`entry_id`, `form_id`)

  INNER JOIN  
    `staff_gf_entry_meta`  `mk8`
  USING
    (`entry_id`, `form_id`)

  WHERE
    `mk1`.`meta_key` = 1
  AND
    `mk6`.`meta_key` = 6
  AND
    `mk7`.`meta_key` = 7
  AND
    `mk8`.`meta_key` = 8

  AND
    `mk1`.`form_id` = 48
  AND
    `mk7`.`meta_value` BETWEEN '2018-12-12' AND '2018-12-18'

  GROUP BY `mk1`.`meta_value`,`mk1`.`form_id`
;
```

I've assumed the following table structure and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `staff_gf_entry_meta`
(
  `form_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `entry_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `meta_key` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `meta_value` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`,`form_id`,`meta_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
;

INSERT INTO `staff_gf_entry_meta` (form_id, entry_id, meta_key, meta_value)
  VALUES
  (48, 2889, 1, 1062),
  (48, 2889, 8, 'John Smith'),
  (48, 2889, 6, 0.29),
  (48, 2891, 1, 1117),
  (48, 2891, 8, 'Jamie Dean'),
  (48, 2891, 6, 2),
  (48, 2892, 1, 1062),
  (48, 2892, 8, 'John Smith'),
  (48, 2892, 6, 4)
;

INSERT INTO `staff_gf_entry_meta` 
  SELECT DISTINCT form_id, entry_id, 7 meta_key, '2018-12-17' meta_value 
  FROM testdb.staff_gf_entry_meta
;
```

Result:

```
# Number, Name, Hours Owed
'1062', 'John Smith', '4.29'
'1117', 'Jamie Dean', '2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with something like below, and build from there.

```
$meta_labels = [
  1 => 'ID'
  8 => 'name'
  6 => 'hours'
];
$output = [];

foreach($results as result) {
  $eid   = $result['entry_id'];
  $label = $meta_labels[$result['meta_key']];

  $output[$eid][$label] = $result['meta_value'];
}
```

And ideally the mapping between metadata IDs and their labels should be stored in the database, not hard-coded in the application.